# Not able to remove ( ) in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, regexp-replace

I am receiving data like 7,432,818 (Imps) and need to load data in column having type decimal(20,3)
I am trying to remove '(Imps)' but brackets are not getting removed using refexp_replace

I am using below code

```
validated_df=validated_df.withColumn('MeasurePer', F.regexp_replace('MeasurePer', ',', ''))
validated_df=validated_df.withColumn('MeasurePer', F.regexp_replace('MeasurePer', '(Imps)', ''))
```

Result getting as:

```
7432818 ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is **escape** characters before **`\(Imps\)`**

```
validated_df=validated_df.withColumn('MeasurePer', F.regexp_replace('MeasurePer', '\(Imps\)', ''))
```

(Or)

Try with this **`or(i.e.|)`** condition in regular expressions.

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([('7,432,818 (Imps)',)],['dec'])

df=df.withColumn("dec",regexp_replace(col("dec"),"(,|\(Imps\))",""))


+--------+
|     dec|
+--------+
|7432818 |
+--------+
```